# why k-meoid clustering use Absolute-error criterion?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I'm student studying clustering. I know that k-medoid algorism use absolute-error criterion, but I can't understand why not use squared-error criterion like k-means algorism. Is there any advantage using absolute-error criterion instead of squared-error criterion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean is a least squares (L2) estimator.

The median is an L1 estimator.

Hence, k-medoids also uses L1, whereas k-means uses L2.